# Python Development option does not exist in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Installer

Tags: python, visual-studio

I want to develop **Python** programs in **Visual Studio Enterprise 2017**,but python development option does not exists in its installer.
I followed the instructions posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installation#visual-studio-2017)  , but there is no python development option in the installer.

I surfed the web and I just have found python tools setup file for **Visual Studio 2015** that it is not working for **Visual Studio 2017**.

Where can I get the python tools setup file for **Visual Studio enterprise 2017**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Python is still not supported in main version :(

Check out [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24315/python-not-showing-in-installer.html):

> The Python development workload is available in the preview of VS 2017, not in 
>   the main release.

Comment: thanks. i checked it. so any other idea to code python in VS 2017?i really got confused!

Comment: I guess the only way is to use preview version or the older Visual Studio. Did you try PyCharm?